# What algorithm does sort use?

Tags: elisp, performance, emacs-internals

I need to add a single integer to a list that's already sorted, such
that it goes in the right place. My first tought was something like

```
(sort (cons newelt list) #'<)
```

However, given that `list` is already sorted, only one insertion is
really needed, which means this solution could be horribly unsuitable
depending on the algorithm used by `sort`.

So, **which is the algorithm that `sort` uses?**

Would I be better off doing something like the following?

```
(let ((tail list))
  ;; The first element is never less-than
  (while (and tail (< newelt (cadr tail)))
    (setq tail (cdr tail)))
  (setcdr tail (cons newelt (cdr tail)))
  list)
```

Comment: I'd use a binary heap (e.g. [heap.el](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/heap.el)), if that was a frequent operation in my code.

Comment: Let `B` be initial already sorted `list` and `A` and `C` initially empty lists. Split `B` in two parts `B1`, `B2` of lengths `m` and `m` or `m+1` and `m`, compare `newelt` to first element of `B2`. If `newelt` is `≥` extend `A` to its right with `B1` and replace `B` with `B2`, else extend `C` to its left with `B2` and replace `B` with `B1`. After `O(log n)` such steps nothing is left in `B`. Then `A` contains  the things `≤ newelt`, and `C` those `> newelt`, and concatenation produces the extended sorted list. Apologies for not very `e-lisp` like language.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have the Emacs source code installed, you can find the source code for `sort` with `M-x find-function`.

There you can see that `sort` performs a merge sort.  It checks the length of the list, breaks the list into half, sorts the "front" and the "back" parts separately through recursion, and then merges the two.

As for whether your implementation would be faster — measure it!  It is more efficient in theory (O(n) vs O(n log n)), but `sort` has the advantage of being written in C, so the result might go either way.  (Of course, don't forget to byte-compile your function.)

Comment: @Malabarba For the record, what scale of lengths did you test it on?

Comment: Tested 1000 times inserting a random number to a list of 1000 random numbers (all pregenerated). The manual method was 6 times faster.